# A Very, Very Basic JavaScript Button in Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I know a bunch of Django, HTML, and CSS, but I somehow never got around to do anything in  JavaScript (only did a little jQuery).

I want to use this on a simple website for the time being for pressed buttons whose look and relevant database changes without reloading the page. I would like a simple example using Django and maybe some jQuery to start learning it.

Let’s just use a Favorite/Like button known from, say, Twitter as an example.

The button has to

- Let a user

  - favorite a post
  - save the choice (i.e. store it in the related MySQL DB)
- Change the text and look of the button without loading a new page

How would I go about this?

Here is the boilerplate code to start it off:

### Django

```
### models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    likes = ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name="likes")

### views.py
def post(request, post_id):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        render(request, 'mytemplate.html',
                {'post': get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)})
    else:
        # ...?
```

### HTML Template

```
<a class="favorite" href="#" title="Like this post">Like?<a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really "very, very basic".

For a start, it's Ajax, rather than simple Javascript. Javascript on its own can alter anything on the page, but you want to send something to the server and get a response, which is more complicated - not massively, but enough.

Note that you really need something in your markup to identify the post being liked:

```
<a class="favorite" id="{{ post.id }}" title="Like this post">Like?</a>

$.ready(function() {
    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var post_id = this.id;
        $.post('/like/' + id + '/', function() {
            $this.replaceWith("<span class='liked'>Liked</span>");
        });
    });
});
```

...

```
if request.is_ajax():
    post.likes.add(request.user)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were doing this without JavaScript, your favourite button would be a submit button in a form, that submitted to a URL handled by a Django view function that made the required database changes.

To do this via JavaScript, you replace the form submission with some JavaScript code that uses [`XMLHTTPRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) to do the `POST` instead.